Github module does not download correctly
I'm trying to run a COPY of github code on my local machine.  I am new to Go and its way of handling modules, but not to programming.  The modules are not downloading correctly, and I do not understand what is causing the error.
The code--written and controlled by someone else--which is currently running smoothly elsewhere is located at:
https://github.com/mashedkeyboard/yapperbot-frs
I downloaded "main.go".  Then I ran:
% go mod init
% go mod tidy
% go run .
The last command gives this error:
module declares its own path as: yapperbot-frs
but was required as: github.com/mashedkeyboard/yapperbot-frs
I am not sure how I can fix it.  Tried many things.
UPDATE:  I found a workaround.  I made a complete copy of the code and then changed the go.mod file in the copy.  I would still like to understand if there is a better way to be able to call the module without getting that error.  I can give a list of the things I have tried based on reading other similar posts here.
